# Twitter Bootstrap Js (tabs, popups, dropdown) not working in Drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal-6, twitter-bootstrap, acquia

Firstly I design the site & convert it into HTML using Twitter bootstrap. The static model of my site is working absolutely fine all tabs popup etc working just fine. But when I give the HTML to developer’s for implementing dynamic code & template creating all things stop working only UI is there but no tabs, popup, dropdown is working I check the JS paths they all are fine. developer even plugged in the jQuery simple tabs they are working fine but twitter bootstrap JS is not working any idea why? Please HELP else I have to design all those things again in jQuery & customize it as per the twitter bootstrap UI :’(

Comment: It definitely sounds like there is scripts missing, or incorrect paths to them. Could you please show us your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the order of script is causing the issue:
It should be:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css">
```

First

> **jquery.js**

and  then

> **Bootstrap.dropdown.js**