# Twitter Bootstrap tabs not working: when I click on them nothing happens

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement Twitter Bootstrap tabs in the following code, but it does not seem to work. The tabs get displayed, but when I click on them nothing happens. Below is the only code I am using. All the other CSS/JS scripts are copied from Twitter Bootstrap framework.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="assets/twitterbootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/twitterbootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="50">

<div class="container">

<!-------->
<div id="content">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#red">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="#orange">Orange</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yellow">Yellow</a></li>
        <li><a href="#green">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blue">Blue</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
            <h1>Red</h1>
            <p>red red red red red red</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
            <h1>Yellow</h1>
            <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
            <h1>Green</h1>
            <p>green green green green green</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
            <h1>Blue</h1>
            <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>    
</div> <!-- container -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/twitterbootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding `data-toggle` worked for me too; this is true for Bootstrap 3 as well. Here's a bootply with a working example: http://bootply.com/74927

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You need to add tabs plugin to your code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/twitterbootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
```

Well, it didn't work. I made some tests and it started working when:

1. moved (updated to 1.7) jQuery script to `<head>` section
2. added `data-toggle="tab"` to links and id for `<ul>` tab element
3. changed `$(".tabs").tabs();` to `$("#tabs").tab();`
4. and some other things that shouldn't matter

Here's a code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<!-------->
<div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
        <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
            <h1>Red</h1>
            <p>red red red red red red</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
            <h1>Yellow</h1>
            <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
            <h1>Green</h1>
            <p>green green green green green</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
            <h1>Blue</h1>
            <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#tabs').tab();
    });
</script>    
</div> <!-- container -->


<script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Bartek; however, I think the bootstrap.js script contains bootstrap-tab.js as well. Please correct me if I am wrong. Anyway, I did add bootstrap-tab.js, and it still does not work.

Comment: You're right, but it also depends on custom build of bootstrap :) ... removed other part of comment; didn't notice you're aliasing namespace...

Comment: Tried that as well; does not work. Does the HTML code above work for you?

Comment: Thanks Barek, it worked! Upgrading jQuery to 1.7 and data-toggle thing  solved the problem. You do not even need the script tag.

Comment: Thanks this really helped - I didn't need to move jquery script I just followed the other 3 steps

Comment: This code should be in the Bootstrap Docs, instead of the incomplete, short snippet that they have there...

Comment: I just added all the <script> tags to the <head> section, thanks man :)

Comment: In BS 3.3.6 , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917435/bootstrap-3-tabs-not-working-properly)  **worked for me** without `bootstrap-tab.js` check [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp), hope helps.

Answer (score 71):

The key elements include:

1. the `class="nav nav-tabs"` and `data-tabs="tabs"` of `ul`
2. the `data-toggle="tab"` and `href="#orange"` of the `a`
3. the `class="tab-content"` of the `div` of the content
4. the `class="tab-pane"` and `id` of the div of the items

The complete code is as below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#orange">Orange</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#yellow">Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#green">Green</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#blue">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
        <h1>Red</h1>
        <p>red red red red red red</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
        <h1>Orange</h1>
        <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
        <h1>Yellow</h1>
        <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
        <h1>Green</h1>
        <p>green green green green green</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
        <h1>Blue</h1>
        <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i want to call a function when a tab becomes active to load the contents of the tab?

Comment: Excellent, this advice helped me. Thank you!

Comment: If you're using this with AngularJS, give ul an id="myTabs", then add:
    $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
    });

Comment: In this answer I like the fact that no javascript is needed to initialize a tab. This helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Had a problem with Bootstrap tabs recently following [their online guidelines](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs), but there's currently an error in their markup example `data-tabs="tabs`" is missing on `<ul>` element. Without it using `data-toggle` on links doesn't work.

Answer (score 18):

I have the same problem, but above some answers might be tricky for me.

I found the other answer maybe solve your question [Twitter Bootstrap Js (tabs, popups, dropdown) not working in Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816505/twitter-bootstrap-js-tabs-popups-dropdown-not-working-in-drupal/8832993#8832993)

> place **`jquery.js`** before **`bootstrap.tab.js`**

Answer (score 16):

You're missing the `data-toggle="tab"` data-tag on your menu urls so your scripts can't tell where your tab switches are:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#orange">Orange</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#yellow">Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#green">Green</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#blue">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

I just fixed this issue by adding **data-toggle="tab"** element in anchor tag

```
<div class="container">

<!-------->
  <div id="content">

   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#red">Red</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab"  href="#orange">Orange</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#yellow">Yellow</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#green">Green</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#blue">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
    <h1>Red</h1>
    <p>red red red red red red</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
    <h1>Orange</h1>
    <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
    <h1>Yellow</h1>
    <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="green">
    <h1>Green</h1>
    <p>green green green green green</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
    <h1>Blue</h1>
    <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
```

and 
added the following in head section
     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'>

Answer (score 1):

I tried the codes from bootstrap's document as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>tab demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="span9">
    <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it works.
But when I switch these two `<script src...>`'s postion, it do not work. So please remember to load your jquery script before bootstrap.js.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I wasn't including bootstrap.min.css (I was only including bootstrap-responsive.min.css).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is another easy way to do it. It works for me but I'm not sure for you guys.
The key thing here, is just adding the FADE in each (tab-pane) and it will works. Besides, you don't even need to script function or whatever version of jQuery.
Here is my code...hope it will works for you all.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="Customer">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th width="40%">Contact Person</th>
            <td><?php echo $event['Event']['e_contact_person']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="Delivery">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th width="40%">Time Arrive Warehouse Start</th>
            <td><?php echo $event['Event']['e_time_arrive_WH_start']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I had already included the  `fade` class, but the tabs only worked in Google Chrome with `asnc bootstrap.min.js`-file. After added  `data-toggle="tab"` the tabs worked also on Mozilla Firefox and MS Edge.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it when none of the other examples did:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem until i downloaded bootstrap-tab.js and included it in my script, download from here https://code.google.com/p/fusionleaf/source/browse/webroot/fusionleaf/com/www/inc/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js?r=82aacd63ee1f7f9a15ead3574fe2c3f45b5c1027

include the bootsrap-tab.js in the  just below the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
```

Final Code Looked like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<!-------->
<div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
        <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
            <h1>Red</h1>
            <p>red red red red red red</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
            <h1>Yellow</h1>
            <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
            <h1>Green</h1>
            <p>green green green green green</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
            <h1>Blue</h1>
            <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#tabs').tab();
    });
</script>    
</div> <!-- container -->


<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only thing that finally worked for me. Question: why wasn't this file included in the original bootstrap download if it works so well? I just want to make sure I have access to all that I need for bootstrap to work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Since i'm working with `Bootstrap Javascript Modules` instead of loading the entire `Bootstrap Javascript`, my tabs were not working because i forgot to load `load/include/` the `node_modules/bootstrap/js/tab.js` file.

[image]

After including it, it worked...

Good Luck

Answer (score -8):

Just copy the script tag for adding the `bootstrap.js` from the head section to the end of the body. Then everything should work fine even without the scripts to activate the tabs.