# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs not activating

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The active tab on the Twitter Bootstrap menu is showing up, but not any other tab.   The solution to similar questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630595/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-not-working-for-me)) was to `data-toggle="tab"` but that did not work for me.

Here's a code snippet of the tab:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="content">
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#skills" data-toggle="tab">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#interests" data-toggle="tab">Interests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#languages" data-toggle="tab">Languages</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="skills">
                <ul class="checkbox-grid">
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="Business Development box" value= "Business Development" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Business Development')" /> Business Development </label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="Capacity Building box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Capacity Building')" />  Capacity Building </label></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="interests">
                <ul class="checkbox-grid">
                    <li><label><input  name="checkbox" id="Art/Architecture/Music box" onclick="boxclick(this,'interests','Training Development')"/> Art/Architecture/Music</label></li>
                    <li><label><input  name="checkbox" id="Child Rights box" onclick="boxclick(this,'interests','Training Development')"/> Child Rights</label></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="languages">
                <h1>Languages</h1>
                <p>languages languages languages</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#tabs').tab();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't add the bootstrap js :)

Comment: This isn't the case-- I've added it to my current site, and it still doesn't work.   This answer was supplied here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630595/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-not-working-for-me, and it turned out not be resolve the issue

Comment: your bootstrap-tab.js is wrong... inside is an html code and not a js code.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the bootstrap.js file for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have included `bootstrap-tab.js` but not the other files that may be required. Please open FireBug, reload your page and you will see the error "tab is not a function" in console, which means that bootstrap code was not initialized properly.