# bootstrap 3 tabs not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I almost copied the code from their website. The tab is initiated perfectly, and when I click on tabs, new panels are activated. However, the "active" class is not applied to the activated tab.
This is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li data-toggle="tab"  data-target="#a" class="active"><a href="#">a</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="tab"  data-target="#b" ><a href="#">b</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="tab"  data-target="#c"  ><a href="#">c</a></li>
</ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="a"> in tab a </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">in tab b</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="c">in tab c</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) you need to put an `id` on each link in the header and that link needs to be inside the `li` which should have no other styles, i.e doesn't need all the `data-target` stuff in the `li`. Your list has with no `data-toggle` or `id`.

Your HTML would be like this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">a</a></li>
   <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">b</a></li>
   <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">c</a></li>
   <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab">d</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">AAA</div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="b">BBB</div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="c">CCC</div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="d">DDD</div>
</div>
```

And you shouldn't need any Javascript, according to the Docs

Comment: yes **this is for worked for me** check [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp)

Comment: in this where I have to add the link because for my case it's not going to the respective page its just enabling active for that li

Comment: i moved the script tag to the index.html / the main loading html rather than the component html and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Removing fat helped, I removed `aria-controls`, `aria-selected` etc. attributes that were shown on the Bootstrap page. Set this minimum used here, and it worked.

Comment: This snippet works until you remove the Bootstrap JS.   So the claim that "you shouldn't need any Javascript, according to the Docs" is either false or needs some _serious_ explanation.

Comment: Hi, I used this code. But I can see all 4 divs at my side, where only one div should be visible (tab content div). What could be reason? @Adam Brown

Answer (score 24):

Make sure your jquery is inserted BEFORE bootstrap js file:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: my problem is fixed by this solution. jquery.js need to be inserted before bootstrap.js file.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I have two elements with the same `id`. I could not notice the cause of problem for a long time, because the first such element was hidden.

Comment: I had this same problem!!! So frustrating to spend so much time trying to debug something when it just came down to the same name for two elements.

Comment: Thanks Tsutomu youhelped me locate my issue with this too. +1

Comment: This is a fix to a common issue occurring when using component frameworks such as Angular and React. Similar naming conventions across multiple components are easy to miss. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This will work

```
$(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
     $(this).tab('show');
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

My problem was that I sillily concluded bootstrap documentation is the latest one.
If you are using **Bootstrap 4**, the necessary working tab markub is: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="active" href="#a" data-toggle="tab">a</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a                href="#b" data-toggle="tab">b</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">a</div>
  <div class="tab-pane"        id="b">b</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was with **extra** `</div>` tag inside the first tab.

Answer (score 4):

for some weird reason bootstrap tabs were not working for me until i was using href like:-

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#a" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
```

but it started working as soon as i replaced href with data-target like:-

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-target="#a" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

When I moved the following lines from the head section to the end of the body section it worked.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case we were setting the div id as a number and setting the href="#123", this did not work.. adding a prefix to the id helped.

Example: 
This did not work-

```
<li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#@i"> <li/>
...
<div class="tab-pane" id="#@i">
```

This worked:

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#prefix@i"><li/>
...
<div class="tab-pane" id="#prefix@i">
```

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to check for this issue is html tag attribute **id**. You should check any other html tags in that page have the same id as nav tab id.

Answer (score 1):

When I removed the smooth scroll script (https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll), it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (dynamically generating the sections): the issue was a missing "#" in href="#...".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this issue using bootstrap3 use the below classlist. If you've copy pasted from the [DOC](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/), It won't surely work. Becasue of the .show in new version.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" >

<div class="tab-pane fade in" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-top:10em;">
  <li class="active" data-toggle="tab"><a href="#">Assign</a></li>
<li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
<li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
```

Comment: Hey @EZE can you please elaborate on why your posted code will work?