# Firebug and Bootsrap3 tab, conflict

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, firefox-addon, firebug, stack-overflow

I am using that kind of [tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630595/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-not-working-for-me) to built my website, everything works but as soon as I open Firebug I can not click on the tabs anymore, they do not seem to switch anymore (I don't get any errors) (Chrome and IE work fine all the time).

And on StackOverflow I can not press the login button anymore, the tag auto complete doesn't work as well (I have to close and reopen my browser and keep the firebug closed).

I have no active breakpoints.

My software:

- Firefox 38.0.5
- Firebug 2.0.11

Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: You should add a code sample, so your issue can be reproduced. Also, did you already try to run your page on a [fresh Firefox profile with just Firebug installed](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Install_Firebug_into_a_clean_profile)?

Comment: Try using the browsers web inspeciton tools. Hit Strl + Shift + I.