# Twitter Bootstrap tabs not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap tab in my code but it does not seem to work.The tabs get displayed, but when I click on them nothing happens and all content show.I wrote my code as same as bootstrap document and I cant figured out where the problem is?
I already read [Twitter Bootstrap tabs not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630595/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-not-working-for-me) issue but it doesn't help me.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html dir="rtl" lang="">
 <title>انتشارات رویای پارسیان</title>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylecss/bootstrap.min.rtl.css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylecss/bootstrap-3.2.rtl.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fa/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylecss/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font/stylesheet.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jscript.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="best-sells col-md-12">
                        <!-- <h3>پرفروش ترین ها</h3> -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" data-toggle="tab">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">تازه ترین</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">پرفروش ترین</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">محبوب ترین</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                         <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">    
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="book1">
                                <div class="sidebar-text">
                                    <p>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</p>
                                    <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </body>
       </html>
```

jQuery part

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#tabs').tab();
   });
```

it's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57cnbLbL/1/)

Comment: Correct your fiddle...add js to js section but not to css.

Comment: @Leothelion correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you need to:

- Remove the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute from the `<ul>`
- Add the `.active` class to the `<li>` not the `<a>`
- Wrap the tabs in a div with the `.tab-content` class

I've created a working fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/a866Lgja/

You don't need the jQuery code either, that will make them jQuery tabs, not Bootstrap tabs: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/